# Query from database

Tags: mysql, query, mysql-5.5, subquery

I have a table named mip. The table has primary key `id`, a foreign key `product_id` and a column `usage_type`. `product_id` is a primary key `id` to a table named `product`.

It is one to many relationship from product to mip table (so a single product can have many mip).

I want to know all the products which have more than one mip rule with different usage type.

Could you please help me write the query ?

This is what I have written so far:

```
select count(product_id)
from mip, product
where product.id = mip.product_id
group by product_id
having count(mip.id > 1)
```

Comment: can you post some sample data and the expected result? or even better create a http://sqlfiddle.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestions

- Write it as a INNER JOIN
- Change `having count(mip.id > 1)` to `having count(mip.id) > 1`
- Try counting just `mip` table for counting

Here are those changes

```
select product.id,mip.usage_type,count(mip.id)
from product INNER JOIN mip
ON product.id = mip.product_id
group by product.id,mip.usage_type having count(mip.id) > 1
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thanks a lot for an immediate reply Rolando ! I have got the result until this part. But what I actually need is the number of products amongst these products which have more than one mip and different usage type

Comment: Which table has the usage type ???

Comment: mip table has usage type !

Comment: Updated my query